# Interpolate intermediate sections

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a geodataframe with lines. I would like to create intermediate lines between two consecutive lines at a maximum distance of 1 meter

For example in the image, I have the red lines and I would like to interpolate even to get the blue lines
[image]

They have a field called 'Number'

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape

# Datos en formato GeoJSON
data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830" } },
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 560826.041657585534267, 4272197.150553102605045 ], [ 561088.454788883915171, 4271956.096630165353417 ], [ 561088.454788883915171, 4271956.096630165353417 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561065.569922782364301, 4272386.332112875767052 ], [ 561187.622541990829632, 4272038.482148131355643 ], [ 561187.622541990829632, 4272038.482148131355643 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561329.508711820701137, 4272139.175558977760375 ], [ 561146.429783007944934, 4272409.216978977434337 ], [ 561146.429783007944934, 4272409.216978977434337 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561218.135696792975068, 4272436.678818298503757 ], [ 561491.228432271978818, 4272233.766338864341378 ], [ 561491.228432271978818, 4272233.766338864341378 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 5 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561297.469899278483354, 4272566.359726207330823 ], [ 561514.113298373646103, 4272314.626199089922011 ], [ 561514.113298373646103, 4272314.626199089922011 ] ] } }
    ]
}

# Crear GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data['features'])
```

Comment: And you need to clarify why/when there is supposed to be a single line or multiple. As is, it is not clear.

Comment: Looks interesting. You could take the first and last pair of coordinates between two consecutive lines and create the vertices of the lines between them following the 1 m max distance rule. Sadly, I don't have time now to redact an answer. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the distance is measured between the middle points of those lines, you could:

1. find their middle points
2. find how many more points must be between those middle points to keep the distance between any pair of adjacent points less than the maximum one
3. make exactly so many points also between the upper and lower vertices of the original lines using [LineString.interpolate()](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.LineString.html#shapely.LineString.interpolate)
4. connect those upper and lower itermediate points to have the respective intermediate lines

It looks like the order of coordinates is wrong in the feature "Number 3" of your original data (the coordinates of the upper vertex come second, while appearing first in all other LineStrings). This doesn't impact the gdf.plot(), but it would not work with my solution, so I corrected the order of those coordinates to make everything working:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
import numpy as np
import math

# Datos en formato GeoJSON
data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830" } },
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 560826.041657585534267, 4272197.150553102605045 ], [ 561088.454788883915171, 4271956.096630165353417 ], [ 561088.454788883915171, 4271956.096630165353417 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561065.569922782364301, 4272386.332112875767052 ], [ 561187.622541990829632, 4272038.482148131355643 ], [ 561187.622541990829632, 4272038.482148131355643 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561146.429783007944934, 4272409.216978977434337 ], [ 561329.508711820701137, 4272139.175558977760375 ], [ 561146.429783007944934, 4272409.216978977434337 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561218.135696792975068, 4272436.678818298503757 ], [ 561491.228432271978818, 4272233.766338864341378 ], [ 561491.228432271978818, 4272233.766338864341378 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Number": 5 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 561297.469899278483354, 4272566.359726207330823 ], [ 561514.113298373646103, 4272314.626199089922011 ], [ 561514.113298373646103, 4272314.626199089922011 ] ] } }
    ]
}

# Crear GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data['features'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color="red")

# get top and bottom vertices of all lines as separate lists
v_tops = []
v_bottoms = []
for index, poi in gdf.iterrows():
    coords = gdf.loc[index, 'geometry'].coords
    v_tops.append(Point(coords[0]))
    v_bottoms.append(Point(coords[1]))

# get middle points  
gdf["centroid"] = gdf.centroid
mids = []
for index, poi in gdf.iterrows():
    mids.append(gdf.loc[index, "centroid"])

# make intermediate lines so that the distance between them around middle points is no more than specified max
dist_max = 100  # 100 cm or 1 m
lines_between = []
for m, m_next, v_top, v_top_next, v_bottom, v_bottom_next in zip(mids[:-1], mids[1:], v_tops[:-1], v_tops[1:], v_bottoms[:-1], v_bottoms[1:]):
    # make a line out of two adjacent middle points
    m_ls = LineString([m, m_next])
    # find how many more points must be between those middle points to satisfy the distance requirement
    num_points_between = math.floor(m_ls.length / dist_max)
    # make a line connecting two adjacent top vertices
    ls_top = LineString([v_top, v_top_next])
    # find distances between the beginning of that line and all those intermediate points
    distances_top = np.linspace(0, ls_top.length, num_points_between + 2)  # add 2 for the first and last point
    # get interpolated points in between
    points_top = [ls_top.interpolate(distance) for distance in distances_top][1:-1]
    # make a line connecting two adjacent bottom vertices
    ls_bottom = LineString([v_bottom, v_bottom_next])
    # find distances between the beginning of that line and all those intermediate points
    distances_bottom = np.linspace(0, ls_bottom.length, num_points_between + 2) # add 2 for the first and last point
    # get interpolated points in between
    points_bottom = [ls_bottom.interpolate(distance) for distance in distances_bottom][1:-1]
    # make lines connecting intermediate point pairs
    for p_t, p_b in zip(points_top, points_bottom):
        lines_between.append(LineString((p_t, p_b)))

# plot intermediate lines
for l in lines_between:
    ax.plot(*l.xy, color="blue")

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [geopandas.GeoSeries.translate](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.translate.html)

Original

[image]

```
translated = gdf.geometry.translate(50) # 1 in your case
```

Result

[image]